# Why do WordPress developers use so many opening and closing PHP tags when developing themes?

Tags: theme-development, themes

This is a code set I copied from Twentyeleven theme.

```
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
```

Why do developers use many opening and closing PHP tags when developing WordPress themes?

Above code can be written like this.

```
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        php endwhile;

        twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
```

So what is the purpose of using opening and closing php tags for almost every line?

Comment: matter of personal choice I guess. Not limited to WP devs.

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask this (also because questions about a specific theme are off-topic), but you should be able to get on the official wordpress "chat" and just ask the people that wrote the code.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has got his/her own style of writing code. Personally, I believe that using different opening and closing PHP tags makes the code easy to read and understand. Theme files carry both PHP as well as HTML code, so keeping the code clean in order to make it easy to read becomes important. Adding HTML in between also becomes easy if you separate your PHP statements.

That apart, I don't think there is any performance compromise if you use PHP open and close tags (please correct me if I'm wrong here). So, why not?! :-)